# CiviVolunteer stopped working after upgrading to 4.7-2.2.2

Tags: civivolunteer

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.20 and upgraded to the latest version of CiviVolunteer from the extensions directory, and now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of CiviVolunteer (4.7-2.2.2) is not compatible with versions of CiviCRM before 4.7.21. You should upgrade CiviCRM to at least this version, if possible. Full details are available in the [announcement](http://ginkgostreet.com/content/announcing-civivolunteer-222-release-0).

If you are not able to upgrade CiviCRM, there are no changes to the database schema in 4.7-2.2.2, so it is possible to downgrade CiviVolunteer to 4.6-2.2.1. [Download the code](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/archive/v4.6-2.2.1.zip) and replace version 4.7-2.2.2 in your extensions directory.